# C - Install GTK on Windows without hassle?

Tags: gtk, gtk3

I'm trying to install GTK+ on Windows but every tutorial says to download 7 different programs, etc. I just want one library that I include in my folder just like SDL has. How to do this?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use GTK+ for development purposes, please use [MSYS2](http://www.msys2.org/). After you downloaded and installed the MSYS2 bundle, use:

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gtk3
```

to install the 64bit version of GTK+ 3.

MSYS also includes packages for the GTK+ language bindings for Python, C++, and others. Additionally, it includes packages for tools like Glade (UI design tool) and DevHelp (offline documentation).

Windows users should not download or build GTK+ directly; application developers should bundle the version of GTK+ used to build the application binary in either a self-extracting zip file, or by using an installer.

Answer (score -2):

You can download boundle pack that contains all libraries you need.
There are different gtk+ boundles on the net.
Here is the one that might help you, it has both x86 and x64:
http://www.tarnyko.net/dl/gtk.htm

Comment: That bundle is over 4 years old, and should not be used any more.